# The set of normal numbers is dense

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

A set $S$ is said to be ***dense*** in $\Omega$ if for given $\omega \in \Omega$ and $\epsilon >0$, there exists $s \in S$ such that $|s-\omega|<\epsilon$.

Let $N=\{\omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n d_i(\omega)=\frac{1}{2}\}$ where $d_i(\omega)$'s are terms in the dyadic expansion of $\omega \in (0,1]$ and is either $0$ or $1$.

Show that $N$ is dense in $\Omega=(0,1]$

**My idea:-** Let $\omega \in (0,1]$. If $\omega \in N$ it is trivial. If $\omega \in N^c$ then we have to come up with a $s \in N$ such that $|s-\omega|<\epsilon$. In contradiction, suppose there exist no such $s$ in $N$ such that $|s-\omega|<\epsilon$. In other words $$\{s:|s-\omega|<\epsilon\} \not \subset N$$ This would simply mean that $\{s:|s-\omega|<\epsilon\} \subset N^c$. Thus $A=(\omega-\epsilon, \omega+\epsilon)$ is a negligible set, because $N^c$ is itself negligible. But choosing $\delta <\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ we get that $|A|>\delta$. Thus $A$ can't be negligible as it can't be covered by any collection of intervals whose sum of lengths are less than $\delta$

Is it okay? I will be happy to be pointed out if there is any lack of completeness.

Comment: These are not normal numbers but [simply normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number). For normal numbers, all digit strings are equidistributed, not just individual digits.

Comment: The displayed equation after "In other words" says something completely different from the preceding sentence.

Comment: If you know that $N^c$ is negligible, you know $N$ is dense by your argument.  Have you previously shown that $N^c$ is negligible?  I would go in the other order, using density (proved otherwise) to show $N^c$ is negligible.

Comment: Actually in my course, (which primarily uses Billingsley) we have been proved a theorem that $N^c$ is negligible. So, I am suing it. By the way, I would like to see how you would express your argument in the form of an answer. I hope it will be a learning for me.

Comment: Isn’t the condition that a set be dense a rather undemanding one? After all, the rationals are dense in $[0,1]$. I’d be happier to see a question about the measure of the set of normal numbers in the unit interval.

Comment: Given $\omega$ and $\epsilon$, find $s'$ that agrees with $\omega$ for the first $k$ digits where $2^{-k} \lt \epsilon/2$.  Then form $s$ by appending $01010101010101\ldots$. to $s'$.  $\ \ s \in N$ because the tail has density $\frac 12$ and is within $\epsilon$ of $\omega$ so $N$ is dense.

Comment: @Lubin: Being dense is mostly independent from the measure. You can have a dense null set (like the rationals) and a non-dense set whose measure is arbitrary close to the full space's measure (like the subset $[0,1-\epsilon]$ of $[0,1]$).